# xpath on xml rss feed does not work as expected

Tags: xml, xpath, scrapy

Trying to parse [this rss feed](http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/feed.asp?feedid=183) with scrapy (0.16) console is not working as expected and i have no idea what is going wrong.  It seems only attributes such as @href are accessible:

```
>>> fetch('http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/feed.asp?feedid=183')
2014-10-23 12:20:54-0400 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www2c.cdc.go
v/podcasts/feed.asp?feedid=183> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/feed.asp?feedid=183>
[s]   response   <200 http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/feed.asp?feedid=183>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=<module 'ebola.scraper.scrape.settings'
 from 'ebola\scraper\scrape\settings.pyc'>>
[s]   spider     <BaseSpider 'default' at 0x3efc130>
[s]   xxs        <XmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.
org/2005/Atom'>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>> xxs.select("//entry").extract()
[]
>>> xxs.select("//link").extract()
[]
>>> xxs.select("//link/text()").extract()
[]
>>> xxs.select("//title").extract()
[]
>>> xxs.select("//title/text()").extract()
[]
>>> xxs.select("//link/@href").extract()
[]
>>> xxs.select("//@href").extract()
[u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/feed.asp?feedid=183', u'http://www.cdc.gov/medi
a/index.html', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634459', u'h
ttp://www.cdc.gov/media/releases/2014/images/p1022-post-arrival-monitoring-300x2
00.jpg', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634458', u'http://
www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634453', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podc
asts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634436', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?
af=h&f=8634435', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634434', u
'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634417', u'http://www2c.cdc.
gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634403', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/downl
oad.asp?af=h&f=8634373', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=863
4367', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634365', u'http://ww
w2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634362', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcas
ts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634361', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af
=h&f=8634355', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634350', u'h
ttp://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634349', u'http://www2c.cdc.go
v/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634330', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/downloa
d.asp?af=h&f=8634329', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=86343
28', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634325', u'http://www2
c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634324', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts
/download.asp?af=h&f=8634322', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h
&f=8634283', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634278', u'htt
p://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634277', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/
podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634273', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.
asp?af=h&f=8634265', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634262
', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634250', u'http://www2c.
cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634251', u'http://www.cdc.gov/media/DPK/20
14/images/vs-crash-injuries/fb.jpg', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.as
p?af=h&f=8634248', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634234',
 u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634233', u'http://www2c.cd
c.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634225', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/dow
nload.asp?af=h&f=8634224', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8
634222', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634221', u'http://
www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634323', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podc
asts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634217', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?
af=h&f=8634214', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634178', u
'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634174', u'http://www.cdc.go
v/media/images/L2/p1002-smoke-free-housing.jpg', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts
/download.asp?af=h&f=8634173', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h
&f=8634211', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634164', u'htt
p://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634157', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/
podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634160', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.
asp?af=h&f=8634161', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634146
', u'http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/download.asp?af=h&f=8634073']
>>>
```

Please keep in mind changing versions of scrapy are not an option, I locked into 0.16 Any ideas are appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the HTML source in a browser, you see that the feed XML is in a *default namespace*:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

All descendant elements of `feed` also belong to this namespace - which is why your selectors do not yield anything. Except for the one selecting an attribute:

> It seems only attributes such as @href are accessable

since attributes do not take on a default namespace - and remain in no namespace.

---

If you'd like to accesss elements that are in a namespace, you have to *register* the said namespace first, and choose a prefix for it:

```
xxs.register_namespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
```

Then, prefix the elements with `atom:`(or any other prefix):

```
xxs.select("//atom:link").extract()
```

---

Find more information in the [relevant section of the Scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.7/topics/selectors.html).